# Why doesn't OpenGL draw object from std::vector?

Tags: c++, opengl, vector, glut, freeglut

Why isn't it drawing object from vector?  Where's my mistake?

It shows m_x,m_y position like this object would exist but this object isn't on my screen.

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
    #include <vector>
    #define NDEBUG
    #include "Figura.h"
    #include "Balon.h"
    #include <GL/freeglut.h>


    using namespace std;

    vector<CBalon> wektor_kol;

    /* GLUT callback Handlers */
    void resize(int width, int height)
    {
        const float ar = (float)width / (float)height;

        glViewport(0, 0, width, height);

        glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
        glLoadIdentity();
        glFrustum(-ar, ar, -1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 100.0);
        gluLookAt(0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0);

        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
        glLoadIdentity();
    }

    void idle()
    {
        glutPostRedisplay();
    }

    void DrawRectangle(double width, double height)
    {
        glPushMatrix();
        // TODO
        // test functions below (glTranslated, glRotated, glColor3d) - what happen when you change their arguments?
        // does their order change the result?
        glTranslated(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
        glRotated(0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
        glRotated(0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
        glRotated(0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);

        glColor3d(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);

        glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
        {
            glVertex3d(-width / 2, height / 2, 0);
            glVertex3d(width / 2, height / 2, 0);
            glVertex3d(width / 2, -height / 2, 0);
            glVertex3d(-width / 2, -height / 2, 0);
        }
        glEnd();
        glPopMatrix();
    }

    void display()
    {
        // clear the scene
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        glPushMatrix();
        for (auto itr = wektor_kol.begin(); itr != wektor_kol.end(); itr++)
        {
            (*itr).Rysuj();
        }
        glPopMatrix();

        glutSwapBuffers();
    }

    void InitGLUTScene(char* window_name)
    {
        glutInitWindowSize(800, 600);
        glutInitWindowPosition(40, 40);
        glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_MULTISAMPLE);

        glutCreateWindow(window_name);

        // set white as the clear colour
        glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);

        glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        glDepthFunc(GL_LESS);

        glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);
        glEnable(GL_NORMALIZE);
        glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);
    }

    void SetCallbackFunctions()
    {
        glutReshapeFunc(resize);
        glutDisplayFunc(display);
        glutIdleFunc(idle);
    }

    void SetObjectsPositions()
    {
        CBalon balonik(0.6, 0.1, 0.5, 0.5);
        balonik.positionSetter(0, 0);
        wektor_kol.push_back(balonik);

    }

    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {

        // it's still possible to use console to print messages
        printf("Hello openGL world!");
        // the same can be done with cout / cin


        glutInit(&argc, argv);
        InitGLUTScene("freeglut template");
        SetCallbackFunctions();
        SetObjectsPositions();

        // start GLUT event loop. It ends when user close the window.
        glutMainLoop();

        return 0;
    }
```

Balon.cpp

```
#include "Balon.h"
#include "Figura.h"
#define NDEBUG
#define M_PI 3.14
#include <math.h>
#include <GL/freeglut.h>


CBalon::CBalon()
{
}

CBalon::CBalon(double radius, double red, double green, double blue)
{
    m_r = red;
    m_g = green;
    m_b = blue;
    m_radius = radius;
}


void CBalon::Rysuj()
{
        glPushMatrix();
        {
            glTranslated(m_x, m_y, 0.0);
            glRotated(m_z, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
            glColor3d(m_r, m_g, m_b);
            glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN);
            {
                for (int i = 0; i <= 360; i++)
                {
                    // 180 - pi
                    // i - degInRad
                    float degInRad = i*M_PI / 180;
                    glVertex2f(cos(degInRad)*m_radius, sin(degInRad)*m_radius);
                }
            }
            glEnd();
        }
    glPopMatrix();
}
double CBalon::redGetter()
{
    return m_r;
}

CBalon::~CBalon()
{
}
```

Balon.h

```
   #pragma once
    #include "Figura.h"
    class CBalon : public Figura
    {
    private:
        double m_radius;

    public:
        CBalon();
        CBalon(double radius, double red, double green, double blue);
        double redGetter();
        void Rysuj();
        ~CBalon();
    };
```

Figura.cpp

```
#include "Figura.h"




Figura::Figura()
{
}
Figura::Figura(double _x, double _y, double _z, double _r, double _g, double _b, bool _u, double _rotation) : m_x(_x), m_y(_y), m_z(_z), m_r(_r), m_g(_g), m_b(_b), m_ukryj(_u), m_rotation(_rotation)
{
}

Figura::Figura(double red, double green, double blue)
    : m_r(red), m_g(green), m_b(blue)
{
    m_x = 0.0;
    m_y = 0.0;
    m_z = 0.0;
    m_ukryj = true;
}




void Figura::Przesun(double dx, double dy)
{
    m_x += dx;
    m_y += dy;
}

bool Figura::GetterUkryj()
{
    return m_ukryj;
}

void Figura::ZmienKolor(double _r, double _g, double _b)
{
    m_r = _r;
    m_g = _g;
    m_b = _b;
}
double Figura::xGetter()
{
    return m_x;
}

double Figura::yGetter()
{
    return m_y;
}
void Figura::positionSetter(double x, double y)
{
    m_x = x;
    m_y = y;
}
Figura::~Figura()
{
```

}

Figura.h

```
#pragma once
class Figura
{
protected:
    double m_r, m_g, m_b;
    bool m_ukryj;
    double m_x, m_y, m_z;
    double m_alpha, m_beta, m_gamma;
    double m_rotation;
public:
    Figura();
    Figura(double _x, double _y, double _z, double _r, double _g, double _b, bool _u, double _rotation);
    Figura(double red, double green, double blue);
    ~Figura();
    virtual void Rysuj() = 0;
    void Ukryj();
    void Pokaz();
    void Przesun(double dx, double dy);
    void Obroc(double dalpha, double dbeta, double dgamma);
    void ZmienKolor(double _r, double _g, double _b);
    double xGetter();
    double yGetter();
    void positionSetter(double x, double y);
    bool GetterUkryj();
};
```

Comment: Did you try using a debugger?

Comment: Yes, I can see one object in vector, which parameteres are fine. When I draw the same object, but not from a vector then it works but I need to draw a lot of objects like this, so I need to draw from vector.

Comment: In that case, define what do you mean by _isn't it drawing object from vector_. What do you expect to happen? What happens instead? Define the meaning of _it works_, and what _doesn't work_ when you are drawing from the vector.

Comment: I checked again debbuger and I noticed there are no parameteres( it shows "???") when i try to do (*itr).Rysuj()

Comment: 1) You still didn't [edit] your question, adding all the information that I asked for. 2) How do you expect us to know what `Rysuj()` does, when you didn't show the definition of `CBalon`?

Comment: It doesn't work- it shows blank freeglut window when I build solution. There should be a circle on a screen

Answer (score 1):

The mistake was:

```
CBalon::CBalon(double radius, double red, double green, double blue): Figura(),m_radius(radius)
{
    m_r = red;
    m_g = green;
    m_b = blue;
}
```

Changing to:

```
CBalon::CBalon(double radius, double red, double green, double blue): Figura(red, green, blue),m_radius(radius)
{
}
```

solved my problem.